# Setting Linked Database (MS Access) path without access to linked database

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

I have an Access system that comprises two parts: a "frontend" .mdb file that contains forms, reports and macros, and a backend .mdb file that contains the data. Copies of the frontend MDB files are stored on each computer and the backend file is located at `\\server\share\backend.mdb`. The frontend MDB files use the Linked Table feature of Access to connect to the backend MDB.

I recently made some changes to the MDB on my home network, I copied both files to my machine and was able to change the Linked Table path because I had the backend file on my local computer. However now I need to put the updated frontend MDB back on the (remote) client's network, however there is no way for me to remote-in to change the Linked Table path back to `\\server\shares\backend.mdb`.

Is there any way to set the Linked Table path (on my local computer) to a path that doesn't exist? The Access GUI only lets me set it through a File Open dialog and so doesn't let me manually set it.

I'm using Access 2010, though the client uses Access 2003 and Access 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code to link to another backend file (say if I deliver and the backend is not in the same place, like it rarely is)

```
Public Function AttachToAnotherDataFile() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo 0
    Dim ofd As FileDialog
    Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
    Set ofd = FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    ofd.show
    If ofd.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then

        result = RelinkLinedTablesToBackend(ofd.SelectedItems(1))
        If result = vbCancel Then
            AttachToAnotherDataFile = False
        End If
        AttachToAnotherDataFile = True
    Else
        AttachToAnotherDataFile = False
    End If
End Function

Function RelinkLinedTablesToBackend(backendPath As String) As VbMsgBoxResult

    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim db As Database
    Dim tdfRefresh As TableDef
    Set db = CurrentDb

        For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
            If tdf.Connect <> vbNullString Then
                On Error Resume Next
                db.TableDefs(tdf.Name).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & backendPath
                db.TableDefs(tdf.Name).RefreshLink
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    RelinkLinedTablesToBackend = MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical + vbRetryCancel, "Error #:" & Err.Number)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next

    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Then when I open my default form when the DB opens I try to connect to the backend

```
On Error Resume Next
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Username, Password, UserGroup FROM Users")
    If Err.Number = 3024 Or Err.Number = 3044 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & "You will be prompted next to locate the data file. Without this file the database cannot open." _
            , vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Backend Data File Not Found"
        GoTo FindBackEndFile
    End If
```