# How to Relink Linked Table on Server without MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2012, linked-tables

In my asp.net webpage I am loading data from an `.accdb` MS Access database that has tables that are linked to another `.mdb` database.

My website works fine on my own dev machine.

When I upload it to the webserver, the path to the linked database becomes incorrect.  This is because Access only lets you use the Linked-Table Manager to assign full paths, and I had to use full paths to locations on my dev machine.

On my webserver, I have Visual Studio Web Express 2012, but not MS Access.  How can I change the paths in the linked tables?  Can I do this with Visual Studio, or is my only solution a coded one?

Comment: Can you temporarily simulate the production path on the dev machine, and then make the links correct before uploading it?  Also, you can link tables dynamically with VBA code - which would be runnable from a macro on the production machine with the free Access Runtime.

Comment: Yes, by editing the host file, I'm sure.  I did try using an admin's unc share - except for permission problems.  I wish I could just edit the file somehow after copying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a workaround.

I ended up moving the dev-db to the same network location as the production db.  That way I can use it on my dev machine and in production and just change the path before uploading the accdb containing the linked tables.  The paths exist in both places already.

Not really the solution I wanted, but it works just fine.

There are some [coded solutions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210062/en-us), too, that I've found.

- [Relinking database tables: Access, VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416747/relinking-database-tables-access-vba)
- [Setting Linked Database (MS Access) path without access to linked database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306231/setting-linked-database-ms-access-path-without-access-to-linked-database?rq=1)
- [Setup a linked table in Access for a path which doesn't exist yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737459/setup-a-linked-table-in-access-for-a-path-which-doesnt-exist-yet?rq=1)
- And a similar but different question: [ms access 2000 changing linked tables without using Linked table manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826373/ms-access-2000-changing-linked-tables-without-using-linked-table-manager?rq=1)